# How do I pass an User Defined Type into a VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba, function, types

This seems as if it should be really easy to achieve, but I'm strugling at the moment, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a User Defined Type, which defines 4 fields relating to date information. I want to pass the variable linked to this type into a function, indexing through each month. Below is the type, sub and function.

I understand that the function has no knowledge of TestMDate type, I've tried declaring the type within the function, but nothing seems to work.

many thanks in advance

glw

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'UDT
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Type TestMDate
        MonthS As String
        MonthD As String
        StartD As String
        EndD As String
End Type
    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub UpdateChart()

Dim Tstruct(12) As TestMDate
Dim a As Integer, i As Integer


    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Tstruct(1).MonthS = "Jan"
Tstruct(1).MonthD = "01"
Tstruct(1).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(1).EndD = "31"
Tstruct(2).MonthS = "Feb"
Tstruct(2).MonthD = "02"
Tstruct(2).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(2).EndD = "28"
Tstruct(3).MonthS = "Mar"
Tstruct(3).MonthD = "03"
Tstruct(3).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(3).EndD = "31"
Tstruct(4).MonthS = "Apr"
Tstruct(4).MonthD = "04"
Tstruct(4).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(4).EndD = "30"
Tstruct(5).MonthS = "May"
Tstruct(5).MonthD = "05"
Tstruct(5).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(5).EndD = "31"
Tstruct(6).MonthS = "Jun"
Tstruct(6).MonthD = "06"
Tstruct(6).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(6).EndD = "30"
Tstruct(7).MonthS = "Jul"
Tstruct(7).MonthD = "07"
Tstruct(7).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(7).EndD = "31"
Tstruct(8).MonthS = "Aug"
Tstruct(8).MonthD = "08"
Tstruct(8).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(8).EndD = "31"
Tstruct(9).MonthS = "Sep"
Tstruct(9).MonthD = "09"
Tstruct(9).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(9).EndD = "30"
Tstruct(10).MonthS = "Oct"
Tstruct(10).MonthD = "10"
Tstruct(10).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(10).EndD = "31"
Tstruct(11).MonthS = "Nov"
Tstruct(11).MonthD = "11"
Tstruct(11).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(11).EndD = "30"
Tstruct(12).MonthS = "Dec"
Tstruct(12).MonthD = "12"
Tstruct(12).StartD = "01"
Tstruct(12).EndD = "31"

   
For i = 1 To 12
    a = proc_res_field(Tstruct(i))
Next i
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function proc_res_field(Tstruct As TestMDate)
    Debug.Print Tstruct.MonthS
    Debug.Print Tstruct.MonthD
    Debug.Print Tstruct.StartD
    Debug.Print Tstruct.EndD
    a = 1
End Function
```

Comment: apologies, I've extracted the type, sub and function from my main  sub as I didnt want to confuse the issue. I only included the debug print as an example of what I was trying to do with the data passed in from the UDT.

Comment: `Debug.Print Tstruct(i).MonthS` you are expecting and giving a struct but then trying to treat it as an array of struct. Remove the `(i)` which is ALSO undefined. So make it consistent, either an array of structs or a struct, you loop implies it should be a struct.

Comment: You've now amended your posted code which renders Mark's comment inexplicable to anyone seeing the question now.

Comment: Arrays start at 0 so you are not defining the first element in the array. So you array is 13 elements 0 to 12.

Comment: yep, thanks for pointing that out Mark, I am trying to process it as a struct. My question  is how does the Function know what the TestMDate type is?

Comment: From where you define it. In your code sample, all in one bas file, all function there have access to it. If it is elsewhere make it `Public`. Also don't use Integers. For compatibility reasons with 16 bit basic they are 16 bit and CPU and all runtime basic code is optimised for 32 bit. Use a Long. You don't even save any memory as it will be aligned in memory on 32 bit boundary.

Comment: Thanks again Mark, I think it boils down to my general missunderstanding of how to structure my VBA code, knowing what I want to do but not quite how to do it!

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code into a regular module, declared `a` as a variable in the function, and it seemed to run as expected, printing out all the different Tstruct elements. Must be something about your setup you are not sharing here.

Answer (score 2):

`proc_res_field` doesn't know anything about `i` or `a`

```
Function proc_res_field(Tstruct As TestMDate)
    Debug.Print Tstruct.MonthS
    Debug.Print Tstruct.MonthD
    Debug.Print Tstruct.StartD
    Debug.Print Tstruct.EndD
    proc_res_field = 1 '?
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, even with my syntax errors corrected, I still don't see how the proc_res_field function knows what the TestMDate type is. I get an 'User-defined type not defined;

Comment: Is your code all in the same module?  That's how I tested and it works fine.  If your Type declaration is in a different module, you have it flagged as Private so it will not be visible in other modules.

Comment: I think that's my problem Tim, the UDT is outside my sub (I can't declare it inside as it gives an error). The Sub itself is the code associated with an Excel sheet, and the function is in a module.

Comment: It all works if you don't declare your Type as Private...

Answer (score 0):

It is a common error, I forgot it too, but functions return something.

```
Function proc_res_field(Tstruct As TestMDate) as integer

   proc_res_field=7

End Function
```

And at the call:

```
a=proc_res_field(your_tstruct)
```

Just as example, setup the correct params and return types that you want to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).